# Cloudformation error when creating AWS Canary

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

I am getting the below error when I tried to create aws synthetics canary
I am using a cloudformation template and the template succeeds if I don't include the AWS::Synthetics::Canary section, so I believe something wrong when executing the canary section.

Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/Code: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2) #/Code: #: 0 subschemas matched instead of one (#/Code)" (RequestToken: 42ff0d18-263e-8503-618e-e0d3d76e3bd8, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Below is the section

```
TreasuryCanary:
  Type: AWS::Synthetics::Canary
  Properties:
    Name: !Ref CanaryName
    ExecutionRoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${CloudWatchSyntheticsRole}
  Code:
    Handler: app.canary_handler
    # S3Bucket: !Sub ${S3BucketForCanaryCode}
    S3Bucket: !Ref S3BucketForCanaryCode
  # ArtifactS3Location: !Sub s3://${ArtifactBucketForCanary}
  ArtifactS3Location:
    Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - s3://
        - Ref: S3BucketARNForCanary
  RuntimeVersion: syn-python-selenium-1.3
  Schedule:
    Expression: rate(5 minutes)
  StartCanaryAfterCreation: false
```

I also tried to have ExecutionRoleArn as below but still no luck.

```
ExecutionRoleArn:   'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/CloudWatchSyntheticsRole'
```

Any help is much appreciated.